# How do I integrate Wixtool set with Github actions?

Tags: wix, github-actions

I use wixtoolset to build releases for my software. I want to automate the release building process by GITHUB actions. Furthermore, I was able to figure out most of the things, but I am stuck on one thing that is in Visual Studio. I have defined pre-processor variables for Files attribute that will be used by WIX.
When I build the application by GitHub actions. I get error as

```
error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.i2vPatchApplier.TargetPath)'.
```

This is my yml file

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [windows-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup MSBuild
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1
      
      - name: Set path for candle and light
        run: echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
        shell: bash
        
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: nuget restore i2V_Patch_Applier.sln

      - name: Build application
        run: msbuild i2vPatchApplier/i2vPatchApplier.csproj
      
      - name: Build WiX Project
        run: msbuild PatchApplierSetup/PatchApplierSetup.wixproj
```

My workflow fails on Build Wix project. Below is the code snippet of Product.wxs file

```
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
             <Component Id="ProductComponent"  Guid="c32e5a53a42f454d9733756c1d7d3027">
                 <File Id="PatchApplier" Name="i2V Patch Applier.exe" Source="$(var.i2vPatchApplier.TargetPath)"></File>
             </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

I want to know a way how to directly pass the path of exe in the Source. It is the exe that will be generated by the job build project.

Comment: Does your WiX project directly reference the `i2vPatchApplier` project? You should not need to define this preprocessor variable - it is automatically created by WiX provided your project is referenced correctly. You say you have "defined pre-processor variables" for WiX - if you mean `$(var.i2vPatchApplier.TargetPath)`, I would suggest you start by removing that definition, then get this working properly in Visual Studio using the variable created automatically by WiX.

Comment: Yes, now I know about $(var.i2vPatchApplier.TargetPath). But still I am stuck on one thing, there are not just .exes that I want to paste in release. There are some DLL, images etc. that I want to access from the path. By typing .TargetPath it assumes I am talking about the generated exe. But I want to access the file from a different location. Normally in VS I do like ..// to go back one directory then access the file. But how to do it by references without defining the variables.

Comment: You can use relative paths with WiX variables. You might need `TargetDir` rather than `TargetPath`. Something like `"$(var.i2vPatchApplier.TargetDir)..\..\SomeFolder\SomeAssembly.dll"` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

For WiX v>=4, it's installed through `dotnet`, which can be added to your GitHub action through including the `Microsoft/MSBuild`. Here are the necessary steps to be included:

```yaml
steps:
  ...
  - name: Add msbuild to PATH
    uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
  - name: Install WiX
    run: dotnet tool install --global wix
  - name: Build WiX on Windows
    run: wix build .\nexus.wxs
```

Comment: And here is a full sample GitHub Action: https://github.com/CharaChorder/nexus/blob/master/.github/workflows/CI.yml